# FullAjaxExceptionHandler CANNOT be shown as response is already committed

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Sometimes on server log, FullAjaxExceptionHandler produce this log :

```
FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during rendering JSF ajax response. Error page '/errorpages/500.xhtml' CANNOT be shown as response is already committed. Consider increasing 'javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE' if it really needs to be handled.
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component for subexpression "bodies" from component with id "invoiceEditorFormPaPr12:tabViewMain" in full expression "@form:tabViewMain:bodies" referenced from "invoiceEditorFormPaPr12:tabViewMain:j_idt1751".
```

Obviusly this my develop error, but if not show error page is difficult to find.
I increased buffer size, log disappear but error page not show.

What wrong for show error page?

In other ajax errors, error page is shown correctly

omnifaces 2.3
primefaces 5.3
payara 4.1.152

Comment: @balusc, my question is how to show error page with FullAjaxExceptionHandler. To resolve find clientid is obviusly

Comment: How should JSF render HTML without a component tree? Fix the component tree and then JSF will be able to render HTML.

Comment: clear, but why sometimes, for the same type of error, can show the page and other times not?

Comment: Because response buffer has overflowed and thus a part of response is already sent. This is a point of no return.